# git svn clone fails because of deleted branch

Tags: git, svn, github, bitbucket, git-svn

I am migrating some SVN repos to Bitbucket using `git svn clone`. It seems that the clone fails when the revision that it is going to clone doesn't exist because the branch it affected doesn't exist anymore in Subversion.

I did

```
git svn clone -authors-file=authors.txt https://my.svn.com/project001 project001
```

The logs shows

```
{...}    
    r12 = f16b3d1014109ccd1c7e24dd70bfa9df45362e48 (refs/remotes/git-svn)
            M       trunk/xx.java
            M       trunk/xx.java
    r13 = 9e61cda58fb2f5afa0a97277a10fd92365f3d1e3 (refs/remotes/git-svn)
            M       trunk/xx.java
            M       trunk/xx.java
    r14 = f9964ce0a8081cf0bf22ee8a5ba32afe725323c3 (refs/remotes/git-svn)
            M       trunk/xx.java
    r15 = ac1f5c4a61346601dd85fbca55bd585ce5fc358d (refs/remotes/git-svn)
    fatal: .git\svn\refs\remotes\origin\https;C:\Program Files\Git\index: index file open failed: Invalid argument
            (in cleanup) update-index -z --index-info: command returned error: 128
    W: +empty_dir: branches/https:/my.svn.com/project001/branches
```

Exploring the SVN repo it seems that the revision #16 refers to the creation of a branch (wrongly named `https:/my.svn.com/project001/branches`) that doesn't exist anymore (it was deleted it revision #18).

I guess the problem is caused by this but after reading the docs and browsing SO I dind't find a way to make the git svn clone ignore this. I am looking for an *automated* way if possible because I have to write a script to migrate several GBs of SVN repos.

Comment: Is this about one-time migration and then only Git is used, or do you want to commit back to the SVN repo from your Git clone?

Comment: @Vampire It's a one time migration.

Answer (score 1):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as a frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to use svn2git (not kde's one but nirvdrum/svn2git because I am on Windows) but looks like I am stuck in a recurrent "problem" `Running command: git checkout -f master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: nirvdrum `svn2git` uses `git-svn` under the hood, so suffers from most of the same drawbacks, just fixing some of them after the actual `git-svn` cloning. I also use the KDE `svn2git` on Windows, no problem here.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try KDE svn2git.